# "Eager" Page Load Strategy workaround for Chromedriver Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, pageloadstrategy

I want to speed up the loading time for pages on selenium because I don't need anything more than the HTML (I am trying to scrape all the links using BeautifulSoup). Using PageLoadStrategy.NONE doesn't work to scrape all the links, and Chrome no longer supports PageLoadStrategy.EAGER. Does anyone know of a workaround to get PageLoadStrategy.EAGER in python?

Comment: have you tried with urllib ?

Comment: yea, why bother with selenium at all?

Comment: Does urllib load faster? I don't know all that much about the different parsers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ChromeDriver** is the *standalone server* which implements [**WebDriver's wire protocol**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) for Chromium. *Chrome* and *Chromium* are still in the process of implementing and moving to the [**W3C standard**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#processing-capabilities). Currently *ChromeDriver* is available for Chrome on Android and Chrome on Desktop (Mac, Linux, Windows and ChromeOS).

As per the current [**WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#navigation) The following is the table of page load strategies that links the **pageLoadStrategy** *capability keyword* to a *page loading strategy state*, and shows which document readiness state that corresponds to it:

[image: page loading strategy]

However, if you observe the current implementation of of **ChromeDriver**, the [**Chrome DevTools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939116/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-devtool-protocol/50942942#50942942) does takes into account the following **document.readyStates**:

- **`document.readyState == 'complete'`**
- **`document.readyState == 'interactive'`**

Here is a sample relevant log:

```
[1517231304.270][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Runtime.evaluate (id=11) {
   "expression": "var isLoaded = document.readyState == 'complete' ||    document.readyState == 'interactive';if (isLoaded) {  var frame = document.createElement('iframe');  frame.name = 'chromedriver dummy frame'; ..."
}
```

As per [WebDriver Status](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/chromedriver_status.md) you will find the list of all **WebDriver commands** and their current support in **ChromeDriver** based on what is in the [**WebDriver Specification**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/). Once the implementation are **completed** from all aspects **PageLoadStrategy.EAGER** is bound to be functionally present within *Chrome Driver*.

Answer (score 1):

You only use `normal` or `none` as the `pageLoadStrategy` in `chromdriver`. So either choose `none` and handle everything yourself or wait for the page load as it normally happens