# By what interface does puppeteer control chromium?

Tags: puppeteer

I see puppeteer can control chromium. But it not clear from its homepage by what interface of chromium puppeteer controls it.

https://puppeteer.github.io/puppeteer/

Could anybody share some details on how the control is done?

I see ChromeDriver. Is it the means by which how puppeteer controls chromium? Or it is via something else?

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Answer (score 0):

According to [the GitHub page](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.0.0/docs/api.md) (as well as the page you linked to), Puppeteer uses the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). For the differences between this and Chrome Driver, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939116/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-devtool-protocol) here on StackOverflow.